# Computing the first variation of volume: all around confusion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}$I've been working through the computation of the first variation of volume presented in Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* (page 196 in the sixth edition, section titled: **Minimal Submanifolds**), and I've been getting caught up in all the notation, and I've been having a lot of trouble exactly understanding how to interpret the partial derivatives in this context.

I'll start with the setup: let $M$ be a smooth submanifold of $N$ and let $F:M\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to N$ be a local variation with compact support. For small enough $t$ we have that $\Phi_t(\cdot):=F(\cdot,t)$ is a diffeomorphism from $M\to M_t\subseteq N$. Now let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ be an orthonormal frame on $M$. Using this diffeomorphism we can write
$$\vol(M_t)=\int_{M}\left\langle\Phi_{t*}e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\Phi_{t*}e_m,\Phi_{t*}e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\Phi_{t*}e_m\right\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}\eta_{M},$$
where $\langle{\cdot,\cdot}\rangle$ is the induced inner product on $\bigwedge^m(TN)$, that is $\langle{v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_m,w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_m}\rangle=\det(\langle{v_i,w_j}\rangle)$, and $\eta_M$ denotes the Riemannian volume form on $M$.

Then we differentiate this with respect to $t$ to find that
$$ \left.\frac{d}{dt}\vol(M_t)\right|_{t=0}=\left.\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{M}\frac{\left\langle\Phi_{t*}e_1\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t*}e_i\wedge\cdots\wedge\Phi_{t*}e_m,\Phi_{t*}e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\Phi_{t*}e_m\right\rangle}{\|\Phi_{t*}e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\Phi_{t*}e_m\|}\eta_M\right|_{t=0}$$

- My first question is about the notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t*}e_i$. Should I interpret this as follows: Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to TN$ be given by $\gamma(t)=\Phi_{t*}e_i\in T_{\Phi_{t}(p)}M$. Then  does $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t*}e_i$ simply mean $d\gamma\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$, where we naturally identify $T(T_qN)\cong T_qN$?

He goes on consider the vector field $X:=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t}\right|_{t=0}$. I'm assuming the interpretation of this vector field is the same as before.

*My main confusion is with this next part:*

To compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t*}e_i$ at $t=0$ we consider a curve $c_i(s)$ in $M$ with $c_i(0)=p$ and $c_i'(0)=e_i$ and let $c_i(s,t):=\Phi_t(c_i(s))$. Then 
$$\left.\Phi_{t*}e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}c_i(s,t)\right|_{s=0}.$$

- How do I justify this? It definitely lives in the right tangent space since $c_i(0,t)=\Phi_t(p)$, but why does this coincide with the pushforward $d\Phi_t(e_i)$. I'm probably missing something pretty fundamental.

Carrying on with the computations we have
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi_{t*}e_i\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}c_i(s,t)\right|_{s=t=0}=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}c_i(s,t)\right|_{s=t=0}=\left.\nabla^N_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}X\right|_{s=0} =\nabla^N_{e_i}X, $$
where $\nabla^N$ is the Levi-Civita connection on $N$.

- My question is *why do the partial derivatives commute in this case?* Again, how should these mixed partials be understood, and what justifies this computation? Even intuitively, it doesn't make sense to me that they should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\p{\partial}$For your second point you just need the chain rule: by definition we have $$e_i = c'_i(0) = Dc_i (\frac\p{\p s}\Big|_{s=0}),$$ so since $c_i(\cdot,t) = \Phi_t \circ c_i$ we have $$\frac \p{\p s}\Big|_{s=0}c_i(s,t)=D(\Phi_t \circ c_i)\left(\frac{d}{ds}\right)=D\Phi_t\left(Dc_i(\frac{d}{ds})\right)=D\Phi_t(e_i).$$

For the first and last questions: I think Jost's notation is slightly confusing here, since (as you observed) its most literal interpretation the quantity $$\frac{\p}{\p t}\frac{\p}{\p s}c_i(s,t)$$ should live in the double tangent bundle $T(TM)$, since the base point $\Phi_t (p)$ of the vector $\p c_i / \p s$ varies with $t$. If $\Phi_t (p)$ really is varying in time (i.e. if $X_p \ne 0$) then your $d\gamma(\frac \p {\p t})$ isn't vertical in $T(TM)$, so the identification you propose doesn't make sense - remember that $TM$ has twice the dimension of $M$, so it is only the vertical subspace of $T_v TM$ that we can identify with $T_{\pi(v)} M$.

What is really meant is the covariant derivative along the curve: for example do Carmo would write this as $$\frac{\nabla}{\p t}\frac{\p c_i}{\p s} := \nabla_{\p c_t/\p t} \frac{\p c_i}{\p s}.$$ 
(do Carmo uses $D$ instead of $\nabla$, which looks less silly.) In fact, from the look of it, Jost switches to a more sensible notation in the next chapter.

The fact that $$\frac{\nabla}{\p t} \frac{\p c_i}{\p s} = \frac{\nabla}{\p s}\frac{\p c_i}{\p t}$$ follows immediately from the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols (i.e. the fact that the connection is torsion-free) when you write it out in coordinates. For example it's Lemma 3.4 in do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry* or Prop 44.1 in O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry (...)*. If you find yourself not understanding something like this in Jost then I recommend referring to a text more like one of these - Jost gets through a *lot* of material in that book, so it is quite brief with the basics.